# Altering left-right sound balance on Android 6.0.1

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, audio

I have a hearing problem and I need to custom balance right and left outputs for my headphones.

How can I do it on Android 6.0.1 ? (I have a Nexus)

Conclusion so far: It seems like Android system is lacking some of the standard accessibility features that can help people with disabilities access and experience the Google Play applications. My next mobile will be iOs.

Comment: Thanks for updating those details, Victor – but this being a Q&A site, answers should not be placed into the question button. You could separate that to its own answer, or have me integrate those details into my answer (and then "accept" the corresponding answer by ticking the check-mark next to it). Which path shall we go?

Comment: Thanks for remarks Izzy. Unfortunately, I do not see any 'accept' button yet (maybe because I have a fresh account?) and this is not actually my answer.

Comment: Should [look like this](http://i.imgur.com/KiFIchr.png) if unchecked (and if unchecked is only visible to the one having asked – regardless of who wrote the answer). As you've edited it out of your question post (thanks!), I'll integrate it with my answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an older related post on this topic: [How do I adjust audio balance of my Android phone headphones out?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/68729/16575) – but it seems that it's not matching recent versions of Android anymore. Like [this CNET post](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/adjust-your-phone-or-tablets-audio-balance-for-better-listening/) it recommends going to *Settings › Accessibility* and check the "Hearing" section (which I could not found on my Lollipop devices – according to the linked question, it might be device-specific and not available on all devices – the [Samsung S6 e.g. seems to have this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJxc0U3tziQ), for other devices it [seems to have been removed](http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/357257-no-more-sound-balance-option-accessibility.html)) for either the "Sound balance" or the "Music Effects" item. So if your device has that: great, you're done!

If your device does *not* have this setting, there are 3rd party solutions. But as far as I am aware, they all require your device being rooted. If that condition is met, you can e.g. use:

- the [Audio Balance](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.robertogl.audiobalance) XPosed module (see [this XDA thread for details](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-audio-balance-t3189218))
- the [Viper](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2191223) music effects app recommended in the linked question (still maintained; the [download page](http://vipersaudio.com/blog/?page_id=48) mentions "Android 4.0~6.0")

As much as I've looked around, these seem to be the only options available currently.

---

<sup>Update by [Victor Spinei](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/177293/victor-spinei) after evaluation:</sup>

In order to download and install this you might need to check:

1. Settings/Security/Unknown source to be ON
2. Settings/Google/Scan device for security threats to be OFF
3. Close security applications like Lookout
4. Do not forget to restart all those services after installing the audio apps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have checked the other related topics and I found similar conclusions. Android system is lacking some of the average accessibility tools.

Comment: Is not easy to install outside Android apps but will test this too recommended by you and update my question.

Comment: OK, trying both  
+ http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.robertogl.audiobalance  
+ http://vipersaudio.com/blog/?page_id=48  
  
Thank you Izzy!  
  
In order to download and install this you might need to check:  
1. Settings/Security/Unknown source to be ON  
2. Settings/Google/Scand device for security threats to be OFF  
3. Close security applications like Lookout  
4. Do not forget to restart all those services after installing the audio apps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! 1) is required for Viper, yes. AFAIK the Xposed module can be installed from within the Xposed GUI even without. 2) No idea what Scand is, never heard of it (new with MM, or did I miss something?) – wait: maybe you mean that "let Google scan apps you install" stuff? Does that get triggered by one of the two apps and yields a warning? 3) As those usually cause more trouble than they solve, I've never used any such :) 4) Well, same as 3 I guess :)

Comment: I cannot use Xposed framework with my Nexus 5 / Marshmallow.
After many hours I found a zip that could help this framework work but I fail to understand how to install it.

Comment: That would be [a different question](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[xposed-framework]+nexus+answers%3A1) – though not yet answered here for MM (the XDA link on the [Xposed installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) page might have details, as the Nexus 5 isn't exactly a rare device ;)

Comment: True, I found the same data when looking for a solution. Now is obvious that I need to root my Android for any of this two solutions, and this is not something easy and comfortable (as technical and secure) to do.

Comment: Not being "easy and comfortable" the first time one does this, I agree. As for "not secure", I rather disagree (I root my devices usually before unboxing them :) if done wisely. But again, that's [a different question](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) :)

Answer (score 0):

Android itself has a.f.a.i.k. no balance setting (which is a shame!).

But you can try in Googles Appstore **"Bass Booster and Equalizer"** - which installs itself as MusicPlayer and allows - amongst many other audio settings - to adjust the balance.

The only disadvantage is that the settings are limited to the application itself (the music player), and not system-wide effective.